# Check for undefined property in object in EJS in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an object, called user, which may or may not have subproperties defined. For example, sometimes there is no "pages" object, sometimes you can go user.pages.someothervariable.

I can see in EJS how to check that user exists, but how can I check that user.pages.someothervariable exists without getting a "cannot access property of undefined" error.

I've tried this and typeof, but cannot get it to work.

```
<% if(locals.user.pages.pageVisits){ %>foo defined<% }else{ %>foo undefined<% } %>
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'pageVisits' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use short-circuiting `&&` --

```
if(locals.user.pages && locals.user.pages.pageVisits) { /* do sth */ }
```

If `user.pages` is falsy, the evaluation won't proceed.

If the chain gets too long, you can try to encapsulate it into a function, like --

```
function getPage(user) {
    return (user && user.pages && user.pages.accountPage)
        || "0"; // a fallback if the left side is falsy
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a more elegant way than this at all: <%= (user && user.pages && user.pages.pageVisits && user.pages.pageVisits.accountPage) ? user.pages.pageVisits.accountPage : '0' %>

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your user has a pages field by running `if(local.user.pages)`. This is because almost any value can be evaluated in if statements in JS. If `user.pages` is `null`, then the if statement will return false. If `user.pages` exists it will return true.

You could do a try-catch to avoid messiness:

```
var obj = {
  test: "hello"
}

try {
  console.log(obj.fakeKey.otherFakeKey)
}
catch(ex) {
  console.log("Caught")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I guess I have to nest a lot to get this to work and the code ends up very messy. Do you know if there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: Using a try-catch could clean it up. I edited my post

Comment: "Using a try-catch could clean it up" -- you're kidding, aren't you.

Comment: What's wrong with a try-catch? It might not be the #1 cleanest way to go about it, but it's better than convoluted boolean logic in certain cases

Comment: Well, leaving aside performance penalties and the fact that there is nothing _exceptional_ here (why try and throw?), how would you recover if all you wanted to do is to simply set a variable `<%= (user && user.pages && user.pages.pageVisits && user.pages.pageVisits.accountPage) ? user.pages.pageVisits.accountPage : '0' %>`. OP doesn't want to log anything, he wants the value to be `0` if there is no such prop.

Comment: Unless I'm very confused about the nature of try-catch, you can still set a variable in a catch statement and run the rest of your code (just tested this out, works fine). Though I admit I never knew try-catches were bad for performance and your solution is more elegant. If I'm wrong about being able to run your code normally with a try-catch please let me know. Otherwise, thanks for the new information on try-catches

Comment: This jsperf suggests that exceptions are pretty slower -- https://jsperf.com/try-vs-if-prop-exists. What to choose, though, should depend on real world measurements, as usual :)